# Update input field value based on adding or removing a div with jquery

Tags: jquery

How to update input field number based on adding or deleting a new div using Jquery.

```
// HTML Code.
<a id="test" href="javascript:void(0);">Add</a> <br />
<input type="number" id="filled">
<div id="box"></div>

// Jquery Code
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').on('click', function() {
        $('#box').append('<div id="p1"><input type="text" name="test[]"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delrow">Remove</a></div>');

        var count = $('#box #p1').length;
        $("#filled").val(count);

        $(".delrow").on('click', function() {

            $("#filled").val(count - 1);

            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });

    });
});
```

Please have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5moq82xa/20/)

Secondly what is the best way to remove a div instead of parent().parent().remove();

Comment: Rather than a fiddle, please use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) to make your example runnable **here**, on site.

Comment: Ok sure,i will do it next time @T.J.Crowder

Comment: ID values **must** be unique. You can't have multiple `div`s with `id="p1"`. So that's the first thing to fix. Also note that you're repeatedly adding the click hanlder to **all** pre-existing `.delrow` elements every time you add an element.

Comment: Ok got it,i will replace it with class @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Yes i am adding it as i want to delete any specific row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to increment count when you add new textbox and decrement count when you remove it.

- I have removed the `id` from your `append`-ed div textbox.
- I have changed the  `$('#box input')` from `$('#box #p1')`, so that
  you can get the count of textbox based on number of input field
  inside `box` div.
- I have added `--count` when you are removing a textbox.
- `$(this).parent().remove();` I have changed this so that you can
  remove one textbox at a time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').on('click', function() {
        $('#box').append('<div><input type="text" name="test[]"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delrow">Remove</a></div>');//Removed id 
        var count = $('#box input').length; //Added input to selector
        $("#filled").val(count);
        $(".delrow").on('click', function() {
            $("#filled").val(--count);//Changed Count
            $(this).parent().remove();//Changed Here
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="test" href="javascript:void(0);">Add</a> <br />
<input type="number" id="filled">
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer,this is what i was looking far

Comment: @KhiradBanu Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

> Secondly what is the best way to remove a div instead of parent().parent().remove();

You can use [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(this).closest('div').remove();
```

For the first part of your question you can define two different event handlers. The second one in order to delegate the remove click to the dynamically created divs under your main box.

In order to avoid duplicated IDs you can add a number to your id: the current div count:

```
$('#box').append('<div id="p' + count + '">......
```

Last point:

why declaring an event handler inside another is a threat?
In your case:

```
$(".delrow").on('click', function() {
```

Because, in this way you will attach more times the same event handler to each newly created divs. This means your code will call more times this event handler. In order to test this part you can add a console log message.

So, you have two main possibilities:

- attach the event handler to the newly created div:

  $("#box #p" + count).on('click', function() {
- delegate the event to children divs under your box div

  $("#box").on('click', '.delrow', function() {

The snippet:

```js
$('#test').on('click', function() {
    var count = $('#box div[id^=p]').length;
    $('#box').append('<div id="p' + count + '"><input type="text" name="test[]"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delrow">Remove</a></div>');
    $("#filled").val(count);
});


$("#box").on('click', '.delrow', function() {
    var count = $('#box div[id^=p]').length;
    $("#filled").val(count - 1);
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a id="test" href="javascript:void(0);">Add</a> <br />
<input type="number" id="filled">
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer,i really appreciate it.